# How to make LightningChart JS available in Python?

Tags: python, lightningchart

I've been searching trow LightningChart JS Developer Docs for an example of using the library in python, but it only says the folowing: 'LightningChart is also available in Python'. Does any one can provide some short illustration of how to do that? And is it possible to use the library in PyQt forms?

[LightningChart JS Python Developer Docs](https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/frameworks/python/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet available in Python, it will extended later while LightingChart provides updates. The docs is saying it will be
[image: Take a look at this picture]

Answer (score 0):

The material is not available to public yet.

As mentioned in the documentation you linked, you can contact to ask for latest information.

You can a leave general inquiry here https://lightningchart.com/contact/